# Finding out number of even paths from root in a tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm trying to get a function that counts all paths from the root to a leaf that has an even number of nodes ( counting the root and the leaf)
My tree looks like this:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree
```

all i got so far is a function that counts ALL nodes in a tree, which is easy enough:

```
countNodes (Leaf _) = 1
countNodes (Node _ x y) = 1+ countNodes x + countNodes y
```

Now i saw a bunch of questions that deal with trees but i felt like no answer helped me much, so I'm just gonna ask myself. How do i make a part of a function stop when a leaf is reached? I know this has to do with my problem to think with recursions.

What I tried to do was to to make list of all paths from the root, but i always end up with a function that gets all elements in the tree and puts them together somehow. 
I'm missing something simple, please help. (or link me an answer that does exactly what i want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's easier to compute both the number of even *and* the number of odd paths.

```
evenAndOdd (Leaf _) = (0, 1)
evenAndOdd (Node _ l r) = let
    (el, ol) = evenAndOdd l
    (er, or) = evenAndOdd r
    in (ol+or, el+er)
```

If you really must, you can then define a function in terms of this to count just the even paths.

```
evenOnly = fst . evenAndOdd
```

Comment: thank you. I never would have managed that on my own, I even had trouble understanding why your solution even works at first.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to make a data type that can describe a path through a tree:

```
data Path = L Path | R Path | End deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This type is basically a list but with two prepend constructors to tell you either go Left or go Right.  This conveniently lets you look up items by path, or you can write a function that gives you a list of all paths in the tree.

```
-- Note that this can fail: lookupNode (Leaf 1) (L End) == Nothing
lookupNode :: Tree -> Path -> Maybe Tree

allPaths :: Tree -> [Path]
```

If you can write the `allPaths` function, then you can write the function you want on top of it.  To start, just begin by listing the base cases:

```
allPaths (Leaf _) = [End]
allPaths (Node _ left right) = _
```

To fill in the hole `_`, think about what it means to list all the paths starting at a `Node` and recursing down `left`.  You would need to have a `L` at the beginning of all of those paths, so you can put the following in there

```
allPaths (Node _ left right) = (map L $ allPaths left)
```

Similarly, you would need to handle the `right` tree:

```
allPaths (Node _ left right) =
    (map L $ allPaths left) ++
    (map R $ allPaths right)
```

So now:

```
> let tree =
    Node 1
        (Node 2           -- L _
            (Leaf 3)      -- L (L End)
            (Node 4       -- L (R _)
                (Leaf 5)  -- L (R (L End))
                (Leaf 6)  -- L (R (R End))
            )
        )
        (Leaf 7)          -- R End
> allPaths tree
[L (L End),L (R (L End)), L (R (R End)),R End]
```

Now, to find the `Leaf`s with an even number of nodes above them, first write a function that calculates a path length:

```
pathLength :: Path -> Int
pathLength End = 0
pathLength (L rest) = 1 + pathlength rest
pathLength (R rest) = 1 + pathLength rest

evenNodeCountPaths :: Tree -> [Path]
evenNodeCountPaths tree = filter (even . pathLength) $ allPaths tree
```

---

Note: It is possible to do this with

```
data Dir = L | R | End
type Path = [Dir]
```

But that can lead to invalid paths like [End, End, L, R, End], which just doesn't make any sense.  I chose to go for the list-like `data Path` for this reason.  You have to write your own `pathLength` function, but this formulation makes it impossible to have invalid paths.

Comment: `data Dir = L | R; type Path = [Dir]`?